# MySql CONSTRAINT issues

Tags: mysql

Fetching back view definitions in final form.

Nothing to fetch

Executing SQL script in server results in:

```
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT `fk_employee_department`
FOREIGN KEY (`dpt_id`)
REFERENCES `r' at line 16
```

**SQL Code:**

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rrm17b`.`employee` (
      `emp_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `dpt_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
      `emp_first` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
      `emp_last` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
      `emp_type` ENUM('f', 'p') NOT NULL,
      `emp_street` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
      `emp_city` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
      `emp_state` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
      `emp_zip` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `emp_phone` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `emp_email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `emp_notes` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`),
      INDEX `fk_employee_department_idx` (`dpt_id` ASC) 
      CONSTRAINT `fk_employee_department`
        FOREIGN KEY (`dpt_id`)
        REFERENCES `rrm17b`.`department` (`dpt_id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 9 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

Comment: Missing comma before constraint

Comment: First,you should get the tour of stack overflow..https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I added in the commas, now I get this:

Comment: ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INDEX `fk_department_division1_idx` (`div_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_department' at line 15

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rrm17b.employee(
emp_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
dpt_id INT UNSIGNED NULL,
emp_first VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
emp_last VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
emp_type ENUM('f', 'p') NOT NULL,
emp_street VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
emp_city VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
emp_state CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
emp_zip INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
emp_phone BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
emp_email VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
emp_notes VARCHAR(100) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (emp_id),
      INDEX fk_employee_department_idx(dpt_id ASC),
      CONSTRAINT fk_employee_department
      FOREIGN KEY (dpt_id)
      REFERENCES rrm17b.department(dpt_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Fixed multiple things:

--Added comma after INDEX

--Removed "`" after dpt_id

Comment: I figured out what the issues were, It was the commas like said before, and having an empty extra table that created issues. Fixed some common date errors(forgot that feb has 28 days) and I got a successful forward engineering. Thank everyone who helped me.